# Google Ruby API Client Create File Response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-drive-api

I am currently working on a Rails project where a file gets uploaded to Drive. I am able to get files uploaded to Drive however am wondering how to get a response that contains the file ID, link, etc. Do I need to use list for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def create
  @essay = Essay.new(params.require(:essay).permit(:course_name))

  # Uploaded File
  uploaded_io = params[:essay][:essay_draft]

  # Save to a temporary folder
  Tempfile.open(uploaded_io.original_filename, Rails.root.join('private', 'tmp')) do |f|

  # Write using UTF-8 encoding
  f.write(uploaded_io.read.force_encoding("UTF-8"))

  # Close the file
  f.close

  # Gotta unlink to delete the temp file
  f.unlink
  end

  # Set Metadata to be sent to Google Drive
  file_metadata = {
  name: uploaded_io.original_filename,
  mime_type: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
  }

  # Call method which will upload the actual file to Drive
  @drive.create_file(file_metadata,
                  fields: 'id',
                  upload_source: uploaded_io.path,
                  content_type: 'text/doc')

if @essay.save
  redirect_to @essay
else
  render :new
end
end
```

Comment: If you already solve this issue, then post your answer in the answer part not in the question as update :)

Comment: My bad. Went ahead and posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have in my `create` method.

```
def create
@essay = Essay.new(params.require(:essay).permit(:course_name))

# Uploaded File
uploaded_io = params[:essay][:essay_draft]

# Set Metadata to be sent to Google Drive
file_metadata = {
  name: uploaded_io.original_filename,
  mime_type: 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
}

# Call method which will upload the actual file to Drive
@file = @drive.create_file(file_metadata,
                  fields: 'id, web_view_link',
                  upload_source: uploaded_io.path,
                  content_type: 'text/doc')

if @essay.save
  render :show
else
  render :new
 end
end
```

I was then able to put the following into my view:

```
<%= @file.id %>
<%= @file.web_view_link %>
```